# Looping and pushing into an array

Tags: javascript

```
var e = 10;
var num = 2;
var results = [];
function powersOfTwo(n){
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        results.push(Math.pow(num,i));
    }
}
console.log(powersOfTwo(e));
```

Alright so I'm trying to make the result of num ^ n return into an array.  I'm lost, and when I put the code in JSbin it came undefined. 
It is supposed to show 2 being the base number and I'm looping the exponents.  So from 0 to n.  2 ^ 0, 2 ^ 1, 2 ^ 2, etc. into an array.

Comment: Your `powersOfTwo` has no `return` statement, so calling it will always result in `undefined`. Either log `results` instead (after calling `powersOfTwo`), or move `results` *into* the function and return it at the end.

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future.

Comment: e is not a number:  powersOfTow(e)

Comment: @JimBaldwin: ?? `e` is declared in the code above and given the value 10.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  Your code appears to work as you intended.  What's the problem?

Comment: @JimBaldwin: It doesn't work as they want, because they're logging the result of calling `powersOfTwo`, not `results` (see my first comment above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var e = 10;
var num = 2;

function powersOfTwo(e, num){
   var results = [];

   for(var i = 0; i < e; i++){
    results.push(Math.pow(num,i));
   }
   return results;
}

console.log(powersOfTwo(e, num));
```

you can check here: https://jsfiddle.net/bvrrmf5v/

Comment: So I had to have the variable result inside of the function?  I thought it could work globally outside.  I put results inside the function and added the return statement.  Thank  you so much, extremely helpful I understand my mistake!

Comment: @kevsykevz: It *can* work if you have `powersOfTwo` close over it. (It's probably not best practice, but it can work.) As I said [in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130878/looping-and-pushing-into-an-array#comment83238640_48130878): Either log `results` after calling it, or move it inside (as above).

Comment: It's not recommended to use global variables in javascript

Comment: @kevsykevz can you mark my answer as 'solved' please.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you Mr.Crowder!

Answer (score 0):

Function should have return statement to return results

Comment: Thank you I get it now!  I thought I could just use console.log!